# Asynchronous request - Data loading after the directive

Tags: angular

need help!

I have a component 'form.component.ts'.

------------- form.component.ts -------------

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [ShopService],
    templateUrl: 'app/admin/shop/shop-form/form.html'

})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit { 
    private shop:Shop = new Shop();
    
  ... 

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
                this.shopService.getById(params['id']).subscribe(result => this.shop = result);
                
        }
    });
}
```

my 'form.html' has a directive what has a variable (shop.state) what dependent of data loaded in ajax.

------------- form.html -------------

```html
<state-city [state]='shop.state' (stateSelected)="shop.state = $event" [city]='shop.city' (cidadeSelected)="shop.city = $event"></state-city>
```

My problem is that at times the ajax request takes long time to load and my directive is to undefined value.

I need what the directive load after request ajax return something.

** **EDITED** **

I reducin my code for better viewing.
summing up... I need to first happen the request ajax and then printing of template. my `<state [state]='shop'></state>` needs this variable for work well.

My form.component is:

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [ShopService],
    template: `<state [state]='shop'></state>`

})
export class FormComponent { 
    private shop: string;
    
    constructor(private shopService:ShopService) { 

        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            
            this.shopService.getById(params['id']).subscribe(result => this.shop = result);
        });
    }
}
```

** **RESOLVED** **

Problem resolved!!! I solved using the method ngOnChanges of angular 2. 
every state change this method is called. That is, after the ajax call is completed, this method is called. Thus we update the variable and my directive works well.

Answer (score 1):

use can use **`ngIf`** to wait until you get data,

```
<state-city  *ngIf="shop" 
             [state]='shop.state' 
             (stateSelected)="shop.state = $event" 
             [city]='shop.city' 
             (cidadeSelected)="shop.city = $event">
</state-city>
```

Comment: even putting '?' my problem does not solve.
solves at inclusion of a new register, because it does not need the data. 
precise editing of data. 

that is... the data it's loading after the directive.

Comment: partially solved!

My problem is this variable always has to exist. 
she will always exist. But is loading after the directive (because of request ajax). when in fact she should load before.

Comment: have you considered OR solution?

Comment: Not solved!
I will post all the code simplified, ok?
I'll edit the question.

to see if I'm clearer.

Comment: problem resolved!!!
I solved using the method ngOnChanges of angular 2.

Comment: every state change this method is called. That is, after the ajax call is completed, this method is called. Thus we update the variable and my directive works well.

micronyks, Thank you for attention.